# Is it enough to use blank identifier for http.Response to prevent memory leaks in Golang?

Tags: http, go, memory-leaks

For example, I am making a post request and I don't need the response object at all.

```
_, err := http.Post(url, "", &buf)
```

Am I safe from memory leak in that case? Will the response.Body be drained for proper connection reuse? Or I need to do the usual `defer resp.Body.Close()` thing?

Comment: memory leaks in Golang ??

Comment: @YandryPozo What does confuse you? Memory leaks are very possible in Golang.

Comment: What would you do with the returned response if you set a blank identifier? How would you close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application must close the response body to reclaim the resources used by the underlying network connection. To enable reuse of the underlying connection, the application must read the response body before closing.

Assigning the response to the blank identifier will not close the connection.

There are no side effects for assignments, including assignments to the blank identifier.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/mNDiyFxZdh)

Comment: Thanks. I know that it is needed to close the response body to reclaim the resources but from my understanding of blank identifier documentation it disregards the data almost like writing to  /dev/null. Can you give me a link about that or maybe make go playground POC?

Comment: You might note that you also need to read the body in full to ensure that the connection can be reused by the transport.